# Mongodb Complex Object Query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to find distinct values of the cities from a collection containing objects as mentioned below:

```
{
location:{
              address:'XYZ',
              city:'New York'
         }
}
```

Can you help me with the query I need to fire? I know I have to use `elemMatch` and `$exists`. But my following query seem to work and returns an empty set:

```
db.collectionName.distinct({'location':{'city':{$exists: true}}})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`db.collection.distinct`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/javascript/#db.collection.distinct) takes the query as a 2nd parameter.

Here's how you should do it: -

```
db.collectionName.distinct('location.city', {'location.city': {$exists: true}})
```

Additionally, you can also use this [`distinct`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/commands/#distinct) database command: -

```
db.runCommand({  "distinct": "collectionName", 
                 "key": "location.city", 
                 "query": {'location.city' : {$exists: true}}
              }).values
```

Comment: Thanks. It checks for a value as well. Mongodb is truely awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

`db.collectionName.distinct('location.city')` should do the trick.